# Representing a symmetric polynomial as a conical sum of squares

Tags: inequalities, sums-of-squares, symmetric-polynomials

This question in inspired by the [recent solution](https://mathoverflow.net/q/393251) to another question.

The following inequality for [monomial symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial#Monomial_symmetric_polynomials) in 4 positive variables $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$:
$$m_{(4, 3, 2, 1)} + m_{(4, 4, 2)} \geq 3m_{(4, 2, 2, 2)} + m_{(4, 3, 3)} + 2 m_{(4, 4, 1, 1)}$$
seems to be hard to prove directly, but easily follows from a rather unobvious identity:
\begin{split}
&m_{(4, 3, 2, 1)} + m_{(4, 4, 2)} - (3m_{(4, 2, 2, 2)} + m_{(4, 3, 3)} + 2 m_{(4, 4, 1, 1)})\\
=&\frac12\left( f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)^2 + f(x_1,x_3,x_2,x_4)^2 + f(x_2,x_3,x_1,x_4)^2 \right),
\end{split}
with
$$f(x,y,z,t) := (x-y) (z-t) (xy(z+t) - (x+y)zt).$$

Relatedly, my questions are

> Q1: How to find representation of a given symmetric polynomial in a fixed number of variables as a conical sum of squares of polynomials if one exists?

> Q2: Is it any simpler if we restrict Q1 to the case when all the coefficients in the sum are the same, and the polynomials being squared represent the same polynomial with just somehow permuted arguments? (like in the above example)

> Q3: Is there a direct "obvious" proof of the above inequality.

Comment: what is "conical sum"?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: Coefficients are nonnegative. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_combination

Comment: sure, coefficients in an s.o.s. are typically nonnegative, and can be just hidden inside $\sum_k a_k q_k^2=\sum_k (\sqrt{a_k}q_k)^2$. So one normally just talks about an s.o.s.

Comment: Yes, indeed. However, I used to work with polynomials over $\mathbb Q$, where this trick does not work (at least directly).

Comment: there is some theory in https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-020-00208-w

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: Thanks! From a brief look, it's unclear if their characterization is constructive and can be turn into a decomposing algorithm. I will need to read more thoroughly.

Comment: s.o.s. decomposition of polynomials is doable by semidefinite optimization, this is well-known. Pick a monomial basis X of halfdegree d, then your s.o.s. is $XAX^\top$ for a p.s.d. matrix $A$, which may be found numerically.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik: Do you know software that can do that more or less easily?

Comment: here is a list: https://sums-of-squares.github.io/sos/
there are more tools that can do SDP solving, but without a ready setup  for this particular type of computation

Comment: but AFAIK none of these will be able to use the fact that it's a symmetric polynomial (the symmetric group will be acting on the space of feasible matrices $A$, and due to convexity on can restrict to fixed points of this action)

Comment: Name of @DimaPasechnik's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393314/representing-a-symmetric-polynomial-as-a-conical-sum-of-squares#comment1003997_393314):  [Blekherman and Riener - Symmetric non-negative forms and sums of squares](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00454-020-00208-w).

Answer (score 3):

For four variables $a$, $b$ $c$ and $d$ we'll use the following natation.
$$\sum_{sym}a=6(a+b+c+d),$$
$$\sum_{sym}ab=4(ab+ac+bc+ad+bd+cd),$$
$$\sum_{sym}a^2b=2\sum_{cyc}a^2(b+c+d).$$
Number of addends is equal to $4!=24$.

Now, let $x_1=\frac{1}{a},$ $x_2=\frac{1}{b},$ $x_3=\frac{1}{c}$ and $x_4=\frac{1}{d}.$

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{sym}\left(\frac{2}{a^4b^3c^2d}+\frac{1}{a^4b^4c^2}-\frac{1}{a^4b^2c^2d^2}-\frac{1}{a^4b^3c^3}-\frac{1}{a^4b^4cd}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{sym}(2a^3b^2c+a^4b^2-a^2b^2c^2-a^4bc-a^3b^3)\geq0$$ which is
$$\sum_{sym}(a-b)^2(a-c)^2(b-c)^2\geq0$$ because for three variables $a$, $b$ and $c$ we have:
$$\prod_{cyc}(a-b)^2=\sum_{cyc}(a^4b^2+a^4c^2-2a^3b^3-2a^4bc+2a^3b^2c+2a^3c^2b-2a^2b^2c^2)=$$
$$=\sum_{sym}(a^4b^2-a^4bc-a^3b^3+2a^3b^2c-a^2b^2c^2).$$
The last identity we can get by the following way:
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4b^2+a^4c^2-2a^4bc-2a^3b^3+2a^3b^2c+2a^3c^2b-2a^2b^2c^2)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(c^4a^2-2c^4ab+c^4b^2-c^3(a^3+b^3-a^2b-ab^2)+abc(a^2c+b^2c-2abc))=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(c^4-c^3(a+b)+c^2ab)=\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2c^2(c-a)(c-b)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)c^2(b-a)=\prod_{cyc}(a-b)\sum_{cyc}(a^2c-a^2b)=\prod_{cyc}(a-b)^2.$$
Your linked inequality:

> For positive variables $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ and $x_4$ we have $$24m_{(3, 3, 3, 1)}  + 3 m_{(4, 3, 2, 1)}  + 9 m_{(4, 4, 2)} \geq 12 m_{(3, 3, 2, 2)} + 3 m_{(4, 2, 2, 2)} + 9 m_{(4, 3, 3)} + 14 m_{(4, 4, 1, 1)}$$

We can prove by the following way.

Again, let $x_1=\frac{1}{a},$ $x_2=\frac{1}{b},$ $x_3=\frac{1}{c}$ and $x_4=\frac{1}{d}.$

Thus, in the previous notation we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{sym}(9a^4b^2-9a^4bc+8a^4bcd+6a^3b^2c-6a^2b^2cd-7a^3b^3-a^2b^2c^2)\geq0.$$
Now, let $$a+b+c+d=4u,$$ $$ab+ac+bc+ad+bd+cd=6v^2,$$$$abc+abd+acd+bcd=4w^3$$ and
$$abcd=t^4.$$
Thus, we need to prove that:
$$3u^2v^4-4v^6-4u^3w^3+6uv^2w^3-w^6\geq0.$$
Now, $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are roots of the polynomial
$$f(p)=(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)(p-d)$$ or
$$p^4-4up^3+6v^2p^2-4w^3p+t^4,$$ which by the Rolle's theorem says that the polynomial $$f'(p)=4p^3-12up^2+12v^2p-4w^3$$ has three roots.

Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be these roots.

Thus, $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$ and $xyz=w^3$, which says that it's enough to prove our inequality for three variables $x$, $y$ and $z$.

But it's really incredible here that:
$$(x-y)^2(x-z)^2(y-z)^2=27(3u^2v^4-4v^6-4u^3w^3+6uv^2w^3-w^6)$$ and we are done!

Comment: So, this answers Q3. However, it does not look that much motivated either. E.g., why did you decide to switch to reciprocals?

Comment: @Max Alekseyev Because your question was, how we can get sum of squares. We can expand $\prod\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2$ by the same way. By the way, I just knew this identity. I got it maybe 30 years ago. The proof, which you saw, I found today. Also, we can always  write similar symmetric polynomials in the form: $\sum\limits_{sym}(a-b)^2S_{ab}$, but $S_{ab}$ not always would be non-negative.

Comment: See also here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/279969/wanted-positivity-certificate-for-the-am-gm-inequality-in-low-dimension/322032#322032

Comment: My concern is a general method, and I do not any see how your approach can be generalized either. Btw, you may like to try to prove this identity of similar kind: https://dxdy.ru/topic145983.html